# CakePHP 3.x: Cache paginated search

Tags: cakephp, caching, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I need to cache paginate result in my CakePHP 3 paginate search.

When I was using CakePHP 2.x I was able to do it overriding paginate function in the appModel. Is it possible to achieve the same result with the new CakePHP ORM? Because `$query->cache()` does not work in the paginate query object.

I have already read some discussion regarding this topic, but I would need an example if possible.

Comment: You need to show some code. `I have already read some discussion regarding this topic` - what discussions? `does not work` - in what way? Pagination [is just a query](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php#L172), anything you can do to a query you can do to the result of calling paginate; you need to show and ask about something specific rather than unshown-code doesn't work, and supported by un-linked conversations.

Answer (score 6):

### Paginate a query

There is no code shown in the question, but let's assume you're starting with a simple baked controller index action:

```
public function index()
{   
    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate($this->Posts));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['posts']);
}
```

First, recognise that the controller method paginate [accepts a table or query object](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.0/src/Controller/Controller.php#L608-L609) - and if a table object is passed the paginator component [simply calls find](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.0/src/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php#L164) to work with a query object. So, the above code is functionally equivalent to this:

```
public function index()
{   
    $query = $this->Posts->find();

    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate($query));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['posts']);
}
```

### Use the query cache method

Only a minor modification to the above code is necessary to make use of the query's cache method:

```
public function index()
{
    $query = $this->Posts->find();

    $cacheKey = $this->name . '_' . md5(json_encode($this->request->query));
    $query->cache($cacheKey);

    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate($query));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['posts']);
}
```

The query arguments, and controller name are used to generate a unique cache key so that the cached result of one call to paginate is not confused with that of a different request.

### Taking care of the count

A count will still be issued when used in this way, if that's a problem it can still be prevented by defining [a counter callback](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#returning-the-total-count-of-records):

```
public function index()
{
    $query = $this->Posts->find();

    $cacheKey = $this->name . '_' . md5(json_encode($this->request->query));
    $searchTerms = []; // define this
    $countCacheKey = $this->name . '_' . md5(json_encode($searchTerms)) . '_count';

    $query
        ->cache($cacheKey)
        ->counter(function($query) use ($countCacheKey) {
            return Cache::remember($countCacheKey, function()  use ($query) {
                return $query->count();
            }); 
        }); 


    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate($query));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['posts']);
}
```

I.e. simply wrap the call to the count method in `Cache::remember`.

Note that the cache key used for the count in the answer is the same for all requests since the number of rows to be paginated in this example *is* the same for all requests. If you're paginating a search for example - the search terms should be used for the count cache key.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is that, **you have to cache the parameters of the paging** in addition to the record, that those are not sufficient.

So you can't use the `cache` option of `find()`.

**WRONG:**

```
$posts = $this->Posts->find('all')
    ->cache('posts_index')
    ->toArray();

$this->set(compact('posts'));
```

**RIGHT:**

```
//Sets the cache names
$cache_posts = 'posts_index_page_' . ($this->request->query('page') ? $this->request->query('page') : 1);
$cache_paging = $cache_posts . '_paging';

//Tries to get data from the cache
list($posts, $paging) = array_values(Cache::readMany([$cache_posts, $cache_paging]));

//If the data are not available from the cache
if(empty($posts) || empty($paging)) {
    //Gets posts
    $posts = $this->paginate($this->Posts->find('active'))->toArray();

    //Writes on cache
    Cache::writeMany([$cache_posts => $posts, $cache_paging => $this->request->param('paging')]);
}
//Else, sets the paging parameter
else
    $this->request->params['paging'] = $paging;

$this->set(compact('posts'));
```

So, for example, for the first page of your posts you will have to use two values from the cache: `posts_index_page_1` and `posts_index_page_1_paging`. The second contains the data pagination.

See also

- [Cache::writeMany()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Cache.Cache.html#_writeMany);
- [Cache::readMany()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Cache.Cache.html#_readMany).

Comment: @AD7six, did you test your code? It looks interesting. Soon as possibile, I'll try.

Comment: @ADsix, I can't understand your code. Remember: you have to cache both the records, both the pagination parameters...

Comment: @AD7six, yes, it works. Thanks. In your example, why do you set `cacheKey` to the view (line 26)?

Comment: @AD7six, no, this doesn't work, without che paging parameters I have a query for the count post. In your screenshot you have 1 page, did you try with more pages?

Comment: Also please clean up your previous comments addressed to me - they served their purpose, I have read them. They don't add any value to anyone else.

Comment: @AD7sixe, sorry, but quite simply my code was designed precisely to prevent all queries, also the count query (this is why I save in cache also the paging parameters...).
This is why I said that your code doesn't work, sorry

Comment: The only problem I see with storing the paging parameters is that you're relying on the implementation details of the paginator component, you aren't calling paginate at all if it's a cache hit, just simulating what it would have done. The controller code shouldn't be aware of how that component works in principle, if it changes the code breaks. It's still a valid solution, but definitely something to be aware of. Note that the toArray calls aren't necessary.